# Clicking a button within searched table using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to search into a table for a specific value (Document ID) and then press a button that is next to that column (Retire). I should add here that the 'Retire' button is only visible once the mouse is hovered over, but I have built that into my code which I'll share further down.

So for example:

[image]

My Document ID would be 0900766b8001b6a3, and I would want to click the button called 'Retire'. The issue I'm having is pulling the XPaths for the retire buttons, this needs to be dynamic. I got it working for some Document IDs that had a common link, for example:

[image]

A700000007201082 Xpath = //*[@id="retire-7201082"] (you can see the commonality here with the Document ID ending in the same as the Xpath number 7201082. Whereas in the first example, the xpath for '0900766b8001b6a3' = //*[@id="retire-251642"], you can see the retire number here is completely random to the Document ID and therefore hard to manually build the Xpath.

Here is my code:

```
before_XPath = "//*[@class='wp-list-table widefat fixed striped table-view-list pages']/tbody/tr["
aftertd_XPath_1 = "]/td[1]"
aftertd_XPath_2 = "]/td[2]"
aftertd_XPath_3 = "]/td[3]"
before_XPath_1 = "//*[@class='wp-list-table widefat fixed striped table-view-list pages']/tbody/tr[1]/th["
before_XPath_2 = "//*[@class='wp-list-table widefat fixed striped table-view-list pages']/tbody/tr[2]/td["
aftertd_XPath = "]/td["
after_XPath = "]"
aftertr_XPath = "]"
 
search_text = "0900766b8001af05"


time.sleep(10)

num_rows = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='wp-list-table widefat fixed striped table-view-list pages']/tbody/tr"))
num_columns = len (driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='wp-list-table widefat fixed striped table-view-list pages']/tbody/tr[2]/td"))

elem_found = False

for t_row in range(2, (num_rows + 1)):
    for t_column in range(1, (num_columns + 1)):
        FinalXPath = before_XPath + str(t_row) + aftertd_XPath + str(t_column) + aftertr_XPath
        cell_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath(FinalXPath).text
        if ((cell_text.casefold()) == (search_text.casefold())):
            print("Search Text "+ search_text +" is present at row " + str(t_row) + " and column " + str(t_column))
            elem_found = True
        
            achains = ActionChains(driver)
            move_to = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/form[1]/table/tbody/tr[" + str(t_row) + "]/td[2]")
            achains.move_to_element(move_to).perform()
            
            retire_xpath = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='retire-"+ str(search_text[-7:])+"']")
           
            time.sleep(6)
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", move_to)
            time.sleep(6)
            driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
           
            break
if (elem_found == False):
    print("Search Text "+ search_text +" not found")
```

This particular bit of code lets me handle any Document IDs such as 'A700000007201082' as I can just cut off the part I need and build it into an XPath:

```
retire_xpath = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='retire-"+ str(search_text[-7:])+"']")
```

I've tried to replicate the above for the Doc IDs starting with 09007, but I can't find how to pull that unique number as it isn't anywhere accessible in the table.

I am wondering if there's something I can do to build it the same way I have above or perhaps focus on the index? Any advice is much appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:

This is the HTML code for the RETIRE button for Document ID: 0900766b8001b6a3

```
<span class="retire"><button id="retire-251642" data-document-id="251642" rel="bookmark" aria-label="Retire this document" class="rs-retire-link">Retire</button></span>
```

You can see the retire button id is completely different to the Document ID. Here is some HTML code just above it which I think could be useful:

```
<div class="hidden" id="inline_251642">
    <div class="post_title">General Purpose Test Kit Lead</div><div class="post_name">0900766b8001b6a3</div>
    <div class="post_author">4</div>
    <div class="comment_status">closed</div>
    <div class="ping_status">closed</div>
    <div class="_status">publish</div>
    <div class="jj">30</div>
    <div class="mm">03</div>
    <div class="aa">2001</div>
    <div class="hh">15</div>
    <div class="mn">43</div>
    <div class="ss">03</div>
    <div class="post_password"></div><div class="post_parent">0</div><div class="page_template">default</div><div class="tags_input" id="rs-language-code_251642">de, en, fr, it</div><div class="tags_input" id="rs-current-state_251642">public</div><div class="tags_input" id="rs-doc-class-code_251642">rs_instruction_sheet</div><div class="tags_input" id="rs-restricted-countries_251642"></div></div>
```

Would it be possible to call the div class "post_name" as this has the correct doc ID, and the press the RETIRE button for that specific Doc ID?

Thank you.

Comment: you need to post the relevant html or url and expected output.

Comment: Hi @KunduK, thanks for the prompt, I've edited my original post and labelled where the edit starts. Let me know if anything else is needed. Thank you.